# How to set value to cell in TableView in javafx

Tags: javafx, tableview

I am newbie on javafx. I already code in core java to set value to table. But now i am converting my project in javafx to maintain code and to improve design.

I am trying to set value to table view but i am not getting how to set value to tableview.

Here is my code which i am using for swing.

```
String testbedName = treePath.getPathComponent(1).toString();
    TestBed currentTestbed = getTbF().get(testbedName);
    propertyTable.getModel().setValueAt(currentTestbed.getTestBedName(), 0, 1);
    propertyTable.getModel().setValueAt(currentTestbed.getTestBedFilePath() + "\\" + testbedName + ".xml", 1, 1);
    propertyTable.getModel().setValueAt(currentTestbed.getTbElements().size(), 2, 1);
```

But i need to convert this code in javafx means from JTable to TableView. but tableview not find getModel() method.

I search but didn't get how to set value to table view.
Please give me reference or hint.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There are pretty nice tutorials on the JavaFX documentation website, here's the one about the [TableView](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/ui_controls/table-view.htm)

Comment: Do you want to edit/add data to a single cell or u just want to fill the table at once???

Answer (score 5):

In JavaFX you generally don't set the values cell by cell like that. In your case, for example, you would

- place your TestBeds in the table:

  ```
  TableView<TestBed> table = new TableView<>();
  table.getItems().addAll(yourTestBeds);
  ```
- you then create the columns you need, by providing appropriate cell value factories, for example (using Java 8 syntax):

  ```
  TableColumn<TestBed, String> name = new TableColumn<>();
  name.setCellValueFactory(c-> new SimpleStringProperty(c.getValue().getTestBedName()));
  ```

  If you use Java 7:

  ```
  name.setCellValueFactory(new Callback<CellDataFeatures<TestBed, String>, ObservableValue<String>>() {
      @Override public ObservableValue<String> call(CellDataFeatures<TestBed, String> c) {
          return new SimpleStringProperty(c.getValue().getTestBedName()));
      }
  });
  ```
- Finally you add the columns to the table:

  ```
  table.getColumns().addAll(name, someOtherColumn);
  ```

Comment: Yes but he is asking how to edit and set value to a particular cell isn't he?

Answer (score 3):

Suppose we have a table with two columns, one for a string, the other for a number. To set programmatically the i-th item or row of the table, we can do like this:

```
//Define the string
String s = "myString" ;
//Define the number
int value = 5;
//Synthesize the item = row
Item item = new Item(s, value);
//Set the i-th item
table.getItems().set(i, item);
```