# JavaFX set color or icon in tablecolumn cell if

Tags: java, excel, javafx, tableview, tablecolumn

I am still fairly new to java programming and struggle with understanding some concepts - especially setting a `TableColumn` cell value. (If anyone can explain this in layman's terms, that'd be awesome!)

Here is my question...

I have a tableview that I load with an `ObservableList` coming from my data table in a derby database. The for loop that adds the data to the table is something I learned from looking online and it definitely worked for me. I want to take it a step further so here is my challenge...

The `ObservalbleList` will have something like example: line 1[toy, high, etc.] line 2 [box, medium, etc] etc.. Now, I want the code to look at this list to see if in that line - get the 1st value and if that equals high, medium or low then add a color icon in the status column that I will assign (or color fill if icon is too much work) [Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wQprv.png). This is my code and it would probably make sense if that color icon piece would be in a for loop as well. This whole feature I am trying to achieve is the same as conditional formatting in excel.

```
data = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

while (rs.next()) {

    ObservableList<String> row = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

    for(int i=1 ; i<=rs.getMetaData().getColumnCount(); i++) {
        row.add(rs.getString(i));              
    }

    data.add(row);
    data.add(row);

    if (data.get(2).equals("High")) { 
        //***set cell icon red or color fill red with padding around***   
    }             
}

mtable.setItems(data);
```

Any help is appreciated! thank you!

Answer (score 0):

For the setting of `TableColumn` values, I will not explain it since it has been answered before, plus you aren't asking about that. You can find more info at [How to set value to cell in TableView in javafx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20547560/how-to-set-value-to-cell-in-tableview-in-javafx)  and through some quick Google searches. I searched for "javafx set tablecolumn value"

You should have an appropriate data model `Class` that has appropriate methods for your data set that you are getting from your database. I do not know what is in your database, so I simply used what you posted in the picture, i.e., `Item Name`, `Priority`, `Status`.

You can certainly add `Circle`s to your `TableView`, but it should be appropriately declared in your data model `Class`.

Some things you will also need that I did not provide:

- You will need to parse your database return and make the appropriate data constructor calls. I will leave that up to you.

Okay, so now on to what I am providing and what I did to achieve it.

You will need to use your data model `Class` to store your database returns in, this is why its important to have it set up correctly. So for each datapoint you care about from your return, it should have an appropriate `set` and `get` method.

In your loop of returning data, you will need to create a `new DataModel(x, y, z, ...);` and add that to the `ObservableList<DataModel>`.

Here is the example base don the picture your provided:

> Main.java

```
public class Main extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        TableView<Data> dataTable = new TableView<>();
        TableColumn<Data, String> itemName = new TableColumn<>("Item Name");
        itemName.setCellValueFactory(cell -> new SimpleStringProperty(cell.getValue().getName()));
        TableColumn<Data, String> priority = new TableColumn<>("Priority");
        priority.setCellValueFactory(cell -> new SimpleStringProperty(cell.getValue().getPriority()));
        TableColumn<Data, Circle> status = new TableColumn<>("Status");
        status.setCellValueFactory(cell -> new SimpleObjectProperty<>(cell.getValue().getStatus()));

        dataTable.getColumns().addAll(itemName, priority, status);
        ObservableList<Data> data = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

        Data high = new Data("toy", "high");
        Data medium = new Data("box", "medium");
        Data low = new Data("candy", "low");
        data.addAll(high, medium, low);

        dataTable.setItems(data);
        Scene scene = new Scene(dataTable, 500, 500);

        primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World!");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

> Data.java (this is my data model)

```
public class Data {
    private String name;
    private String priority;
    private Circle status;

    public Data (String name, String priority){
        setName(name);
        setPriority(priority);
        setStatus(priority);
    }

    public String getName(){
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name){
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getPriority(){
        return priority;
    }
    public void setPriority(String priority){
        this.priority = priority;
    }

    public Circle getStatus(){
        return status;
    }
    public void setStatus(String priority){
        Circle c = new Circle(5);
        switch(priority){
            case "high":
                c.setFill(Color.GREEN);
                break;
            case "medium":
                c.setFill(Color.YELLOW);
                break;
            case "low":
                c.setFill(Color.RED);
                break;
            default:
        }
        status = c;
    }
}
```

As you can see, I did not provide the `status` in the `Constructor`, but rather I used the `Priority` to determine it.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I added more content - if you wouldn't mind taking a look
@HypnicJerk