# Best way to present table data in JavaFX

Tags: javafx

I'm writing an business application that imports bank statements and allows the user to categorise entries.   Once they have done this they can preview their tax statement such as below:

[image: SceneBuilder View of Summary FXML]

This is currently a gridpane with each cell containing a vbox containing a label and textfield.    **I don't like it.**  Its bulky & inflexible.

Each cell is a unique calculation or sum and I'm finding it difficult to get a layout/grouping that I am happy with. I'd like to add descriptive notes adajecent to some cells but this could/would throw the layout out.

I thought about setting specific cells in a tableview like this table:

[image: Using a static class]

but seeing this thread [How to set value to cell in TableView in javafx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20547560/how-to-set-value-to-cell-in-tableview-in-javafx) and the comment

> In JavaFX you generally don't set the values cell by cell like that.

I'm wondering what would be best practice?  It seems a bit short sighted that tableviews cannot be used to present (non uniform) non-jpa data.

**Update**  My current work in progress alternative solution is shown in the table above populated by a small class with 3 variables (category, amount and description). Seems better practice.

Comment: *"I'd like to add notes adajecent to cells but cannot."* Why not? It should be simple enough to insert a new child at the next/previous row/column. Could you improve the description of the requirements?

Comment: @fabian,  hopefully this is better explained.   Regards

Comment: *"populated by a small static class"* Why is the class static? Could you show your code?

Comment: @lu.koerfer Surely the fact that its static is irrelevant.    My questions relates to best practice for showing a particular type or form of data.

Comment: Unclear what you're asking. What do you mean by *"tableviews cannot be used to present (non uniform) non-jpa data"*? This doesn't seem to be a true statement, but maybe I don't understand what you mean by "non uniform" here. `TableView` can certainly be used to present data that doesn't come from a JPA layer.

Comment: @James_D.   By non-uniform I mean data where each element is unique in its source and/or format unlike a dB query which gives a number of records that present like data.   Some of my data is a sum of a category other is a percentage of a total.   Some need notes others don't.   In the end I have followed through with my small class solution so each value I need gets created as an instance of this class and then I use that to set items.